# handleSubmit not getting called

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I'm working on an app that uses strapi as the backenbd and react as the front
I'm using react hooks to build a login form. However my form submit does not call the submit handler

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const Login = () => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({ identifier: '', password: '' });
    const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
      setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));

    const handleSubmit = async() => {
        console.log('handleSubmit')
      try {
        const response = await fetch('./auth/local', { method: 'POST', body: state})
        console.log(response)
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>

          <label htmlForm="identifier">identifier</label>
          <input
            id="identifier"
            name="identifier"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={state.identifier}
          />
          <label htmlForm="password">password</label>
          <input
            id="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={state.password}
          />
        <button onClick={() => handleSubmit}></button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default Login;
```

the handleSubmit function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to trigger the `submit`.

You can add a button to trigger a submit as shown below.

```
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlForm="identifier">identifier</label>
        <input
          id="identifier"
          name="identifier"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={state.identifier}
        />
        <label htmlForm="password">password</label>
        <input
          id="password"
          name="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={state.password}
        />
                   
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

You can try it out out this Sandbox.

[image: Edit so.answer.57642868]

Comment: shouldnt it work outside a form?
```
<div>
        <label htmlFor="identifier">identifier</label>
        <input
          id="identifier"
          name="identifier"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={state.identifier}
        />
        <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
        <input
          id="password"
          name="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={state.password}
        />
                   
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>

      <label htmlForm="identifier">identifier</label>
      <input
        id="identifier"
        name="identifier"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={state.identifier}
      />
      <label htmlForm="password">password</label>
      <input
        id="password"
        name="password"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={state.password}
      />
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}></button>
  </div>
```